overlay around image in css
I want to make an overlay around image like this

I tried this but it's not look like I wanted
 background-image: linear-gradient(
        90deg,
        #171717 0%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.986) 0.97%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.945) 2.07833333%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.883) 3.29666667%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.803) 4.60166667%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.711) 5.96666667%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.61) 7.365%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.504) 8.77166667%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.398) 10.16%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.296) 11.505%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.203) 12.78%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.122) 13.95833333%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.059) 15.01666667%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.016) 15.92833333%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0) 16.66666667%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0) 83.33333333%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.016) 84.07166667%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.059) 84.98333333%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.122) 86.04166667%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.203) 87.22%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.296) 88.495%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.398) 89.84%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.504) 91.22833333%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.61) 92.635%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.711) 94.03333333%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.803) 95.39833333%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.883) 96.70333333%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.945) 97.92166667%,
        rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.986) 99.03%,
        #171717
      );


I want more overlay in left and right and a little on the top

Its easily achievable by using two layers, one for image & second for shadow. I have  explained in detail in response & here is code pen link .



.image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.image-container::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1; 
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 16%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 
  50%),
  linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 6%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 30%),
  linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 12%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 30%);
}
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/977080/pexels-photo-977080.jpeg? 
  auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="your image">
</div>



Adjust the image Height and opacity as per your need.

The code looks OK but it would be useful to have a brief description of what has been changed from the question's code and why it works.

I have simpler approach to achieve same result. Inside a parent div we need to have two children one img and another div for imageShadow. Now we will align imageShadow above img so that shadow would be apply on image.
Inside our innerShadow we add box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px 30px black; which will add inner shadow effect for our image.
It might sound complex but its very simple and much more easy to play with. I hope this will fix issue and if I am missing out or misunderstood something please share.
Here is codepen link if you want to play around. Please open output in full page.


body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.image-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image-container img{
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 5
}

.imageShadow{
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px 100px black;
  
}
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="imageShadow"></div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1721635513019-4dd5f5c18042?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE3MjIxNDU0NTh8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85" alt="Your Image" class="image" />
</div>




All you need is radial gradient in the before or after of the image div,


.effect{
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
.effect:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, rgba(6, 6, 6, 0) 19%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    z-index:1;
}
<div class="effect">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/R09kvXpk/251-1920x1080.jpg">
</div>



